# Problem passing from a static method a created instance of a subtype to a closure

Tags: swift, oop, types

My idea is in a base class's static method to create an instance of a subtype and then pass it as a parameter of the **created type** to a provided closure:

```
let subtypeInstance = SubType.baseCreateInstanceOfSubtype() { new in // `new` is expected to be of type `SubType` which declares a property `v`
    new.v = 1
}
```

Here's a full example of implementation:

```
class Foo {
    required init() {}
    static func createSubtype(initialize: (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        let foo = Self()
        initialize(foo)
        return foo
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    var v: Int?
}

let bar = Bar.createSubtype() { o in
    o.v = 1
}
```

Doing that the Swift compiler yields an error `Value of type 'Self' has no member 'v'`.
`print(type(of: o))` in the closure gives `Bar`. Adding explicit casting of `o` to `Bar`, `(o as! Bar).v = 1`, solves the problem, but I don't understand why it doesn't work without the explicit casting while the type of `o` seems to be correct.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly related to `Self` being covariant. The compiler doesn't really know what `Self` the closure parameter is. It only knows that it is a subclass of `Foo`. This is why you can make `o` be `Foo` or any superclass of `Foo`.

On the other hand, the compiler *can* infer that the `Self` in the return type is `Bar`. My guess is that the compiler is specifically designed to analyse `Self`s in return types, property types and subscripts, because these are the most common use cases of `Self`. It doesn't do anything special for `Self` in `(Self) -> Void`, so it remains "some subclass of `Foo`".

I would not use self types here. Make the function global, and use generics instead:

```
func createSubclass<T: Foo>(initialize: (T) -> Void) -> T {
    let foo = T()
    initialize(foo)
    return foo
}
```

Usage:

```
let bar: Bar = createSubclass { o in
    o.v = 1
}
```

Note that now `Bar` is used as a type annotation to help infer `T`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. According to the [Expanding Swift Self to class members and value types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) implemented in Swift 5.1 using `Self` still may be appropriate here. But the suggested solution looks like the best fallback.